# Finding the minimum value of a complex number

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

If $z$ is a complex number satisfying $|z^2+1| = 4|z|$ . Then prove that the minimum value of $|z|$ is $4$

This is how I attempted the problem ,

$\frac{|z^2+1|}{|z|} = 4$

Therefore ,

$|z + \frac{1}{z}| = 4$

How do I proceed from here ?

According to the solution of the above problem the next step would be as follows

$||z| - |\frac{1}{z}|| ≤ 4$

We can then form a quadratic in $z$ to find out the least value of $z$. However , I’m stuck at the first step of the solution . How does $|z + \frac{1}{z}| = 4$ imply $||z| - |\frac{1}{z}|| ≤ 4$ ? Please help .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implication$$\left|z+\frac1z\right|=4\implies\left||z|-\left|\frac1z\right|\right|\leqslant4$$comes from the inequality$$(\forall z,w\in\mathbb{C}):|z-w|\geqslant\bigl||z|-|w|\bigr|.$$

Comment: Thank you very much for helping , but I just wanted to know , that among the four triangle inequalities that I’ve read for complex numbers , one of them is $|z_1 - z_2| ≥ |z_1| - |z_2|$ the RHS of this inequality does not contain a modulus over the entire side. May I please know which inequality have you used , and if it is this then is it possible to change it that way ?

Comment: @Aditi I used the inequality that you mentioned. Note that exchanging $z_1$ with $z_2$ you get $|z_2-z_1|\geqslant|z_2|-|z_1|$, which is the same thing as asserting that $|z_1-z_2|\geqslant-\bigl(|z_1|-|z_2|\bigr)$. But since $|z_1-z_2|$ is greater than or equal to both $|z_1|-|z_2|$ and to its symmetric, and since one of these two numbers is $\bigl||z_1|-|z_2|\bigr|$, you get the inequality that I mentioned.

Comment: And could you please tell what is $w$ in your case ? Is it $\frac{1}{z}$ ? And if it is $\frac{1}{z}$ then shouldn’t the LHS of the inequality become $|z- \frac{1}{z}|$ ?

Comment: Oh wait ! I get it. Have you used $w = -\frac{1}{z}$ ?

Comment: @Aditi $$4=\left|z+\frac1z\right|=\left|z-\left(-\frac1z\right)\right|\geqslant\left||z|-\left|-\frac1z\right|\right|=\left||z|-\left|\frac1z\right|\right|.$$

Comment: Alright ! I get it now ! Thank you very much for helping me !!

Answer (score 3):

This follows from a version of the reverse triangle inequality, in your case $$\lvert\lvert z\rvert-\lvert\frac{1}{z}\rvert\rvert\leq\lvert z+\frac{1}{z}\rvert.$$

Answer (score 2):

To tell it in another way, since:
$$
\left| {z + 1/z} \right| = \left| {\left| z \right|e^{\;i\,\varphi }  + 1/\left| z \right|e^{\; - i\,\varphi } } \right| = \left| {e^{\;i\,\varphi } \left( {\left| z \right| + 1/\left| z \right|e^{\; - i2\,\varphi } } \right)} \right| = \left| {\left| z \right| + 1/\left| z \right|e^{\; - i2\,\varphi } } \right|
$$
then
$$
\left| {\left| z \right| - 1/\left| z \right|} \right| \le \left| {z + 1/z} \right| \le \left| {\left| z \right| + 1/\left| z \right|} \right|
$$